# query don't return same result value bigquery

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

when I run my query on the interface proposed by Bigquery and I run it on a python script I don't get the same result

the table that I am querying is the correct one and the query is a simple query of a simple count and group by

qyery on BQ:

```
SELECT Criticity,COUNT(*) as nb
                             FROM  `project.mytable` 
                             WHERE project_key='pppp'  AND Criticity NOT IN ("") 
                                   AND  Components like '%%' 
                           GROUP BY
                               Criticity
                           ORDER BY Criticity
```

query on python script (parameters are passed correctly)

```
query = f"""
                             SELECT Criticity,COUNT(*) as nb
                             FROM  `{same.table}` 
                             WHERE project_key='{projectKey}'  AND Criticity NOT IN ("") 
                                   AND  Components like '{component}' 
                           GROUP BY
                               Criticity
                           ORDER BY Criticity
                             """
```

Comment: What's the result of `print(query)`?

Comment: I checked and it's the same one that I paste on BQ

Comment: And how are you running the query?

Comment: Also: in what way is the result different?

Comment: Additional question: Are you sure you're on the same database?

Comment: i get the result in Dataframe 
      dataframe = (
        query_job
            .result()
            .to_dataframe(
            
            create_bqstorage_client=True,
        )
    )
    return dataframe

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by clearing firefox cache and reload.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string formatting,  try in this way:

```
query = "
                             SELECT Criticity,COUNT(*) as nb
                             FROM  %s 
                             WHERE project_key=%s  AND Criticity NOT IN ("") 
                                   AND  Components like %s 
                           GROUP BY
                               Criticity
                           ORDER BY Criticity
                             " % (same.table, projectKey, component)
```